# What is a word for "to create a universe"? Can 'universalize' be used?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage, verbs, productive-affixes

Per *[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/universalize)*, *universalize* means:

> Give a universal character or application to (something, especially something abstract) 
> ‘*theories that universalize experience’*

Can this definition include the sense "to create a universe" within a context? Per *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/universal)*, *universal* also means:

> Of or pertaining to the universe.

In many other credible dictionaries, *universalize* refers to a more succinct definition: "to generalize, to make available universally". For example:

> to make universal : Generalize - *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/universalize)*

When I did a Google search for `dictionary "to create a universe"`, no word with this meaning came up. What would be a suitable word/verb for 'to create a universe'?

Possible example sentence:

> And he created a universe, gazed on the vastness and magnificence around him, and said 'I _______' (created a universe).

Comment: Your *other dictionaries* and Lexico definitions are similar. Creating a universe is not.

Comment: universalize is to make univers**al**, not to create a universe.

Comment: I've included further research for the OP and tried my best to make it nice and shiny; and worthy of re-opening. Since it was tagged with `single-word-requests`, I've added details related to this tag also. I believe it is a very good and useful question, and it has good answers. I believe it deserves recognition. Thank you.

Comment: In what semantic meaning you wish it to exist? If we talk about creation of real world, the act is Genesis, but no verb aside of "create" can be used.  So God can be referred to as a Creator.  If it's a creation of some fictional setting, you can use world-building or worldbuilding as a noun or gerund. No special verb anyway. "To world-build" may exist only because "everything is a verb" principle.

Comment: Thanks @ermanen for clarifying my question neatly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Universalize* doesn't have the sense 'to create a universe' as the productive suffix *-ize* (*-ise*) modifies the word *universal*, not *universe*.

The correct formation would be *universize* (*universe* + *-ize*) for the meaning 'to create a universe'; however, it is not defined in any dictionaries and it is not a concept that necessitates a single word. Although, you can use it as a nonce word for your needs.

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/214783?redirectedFrom=universal#eid)* says the sense "Of or relating to the universe in general or to all things in it" for *universal* is poetic or rhetorical, and now rare. And surprisingly, *OED* also lists an obsolete sense of *universal* meaning 'The universe'.

There is the word *cosmogony* with the meaning of 'the creation of the universe (cosmos)' but it is generally used in extended senses like the study of the origin of the universe or the theories/models involved within that context. As its etymology suggests:

> From Ancient Greek κοσμογονία (*kosmogonía*), from κόσμος (*kósmos*, “world”) + γόνος (*gónos*, “creation”). - *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cosmogony)*

I surmised that *cosmogonize* could mean 'to create a universe' but it has another meaning related to the extended senses (and the right formation could be 'cosmosize' for the meaning 'to create a universe'):

> cosmogonize: To theorize a cosmogony - *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cosmogonize)*

Although, you could possibly use *cosmogonize* in the sense 'to create a universe', perhaps within the right context in a fictional story or figuratively. I could also find instances of *[cosmosize](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cosmosized%22&rlz=1C1VDKB_enCA994CA994&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj8tSg6vL4AhVqhIkEHY6pAEAQ_AUoAXoECAEQCw&biw=1536&bih=746&dpr=1.25)* in Google Books.

Additionally, *[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/42222)* lists *cosmize* as a rare word, formed as *cosmism n.* + *-ize* suffix. It has a slightly different meaning and it is used figuratively in the only citation provided:

> *rare* 
> *transitive.* To make into a cosmos.
>
> It's the duty of man to try..to cosmise his own particular little corner of it. 
> 1884     G. Allen *Philistia* III. 28

Comment: @StuartF _Universify_ or _cosmify_ could mean more like "to make or become cosmic, universe-like".

Answer (score 4):

I don't beleive so. The suffix -ize/-ise (acorrding to https://www.thoughtco.com/common-suffixes-in-english-1692725 and a few other sources) means to become, and the definition of the word universal is "of, affecting, or done by all people or things in the world or in a particular group; applicable to all cases." (-*Oxford Dictionary*) in the case of adjectives. And for nouns the definition is "a person or thing having universal effect, currency, or application." (-*Oxford Dictionary*). Putting two and two together the definition of "Univeralizing" would be "to become or make something or someone universally applicable or effective" or something along those lines. So gramatically it would not make sense, no. Hope this answered your question!

Comment: A "*universal character or application*", as your given definition reads, means that character or application is recognized or applied all over the world (in this sense '*universal*' is synonymous to '*mondial*').

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, "universalize" means to make something more general or more broadly applicable.  It doesn't have anything to do with creating a universe.

If you're looking for a word for "creating a universe" in the literary sense (for example, an author trying create a "universe" for a book they are writing), a commonly used term is "worldbuilding":  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldbuilding.

However, I don't believe there's a single word that fits your example sentence.  Probably the best single word for that sentence ("I ____") is simply "I create".